# How to generate svg in folder and force download as svg file using php?

Tags: php, svg

I have generate output as svg in html using php and have to force download it as svg image when i click download as svg. how to generate it as svg image when i click download.

```
foreach($items as $item){
   // echo $item->top;
$top       = str_replace('px', '', $item['top']);
$left       = str_replace('px', '', $item['left']);
     echo '<div style="background-color:#fff;width:333.333px;height:500px;">'; 
     echo '<div style="position:absolute;top:'.$top.';left:'.$left.'">';
     $svg_element =  $item['svg'];
     echo $svg_element;  
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}

   // output
   <div style="background-color:#fff;width:333.333px;height:500px;"><div style="position:absolute;top:235;left:64.0667">
<svg width="198" height="132" viewBox="0 0 99 52" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="none">
 <defs><style>@font-face{font-family: 'Twine';src: url("data:application/font-ttf;charset=utf-8;base64,")
 <g id="0.38592716854139286"><text fill="#000000" stroke="none" stroke-  width="0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x="32" y="39"   text-anchor="middle" font-size="40.30555555555556" font-family="Twine" data-textcurve="0" data-itemzoom="1 1" itemzoom="0.5 0.3939393939393939">  <tspan dy="0" x="50%">Hello</tspan></text></g>
```

Comment: have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SVG there should not be any div. so i have removed div and created svg with width and height, background color and put the contents in the file save it as .svg extension

```
$op =  '<svg width="'.$template_width.'" height="'.$template_height.'">';
foreach($items as $item){
   // echo $item->top;
$top       = str_replace('px', '', $item['top']);
$left       = str_replace('px', '', $item['left']);
    $op .= str_replace('<svg ', '<svg y="'.$top.'" x="'.$left.'" ', $item['svg']);

}
$op .= '</svg>';
$filename = '/front_'.time().'.svg';
file_put_contents(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).$filename, $op);
```